# Oracle gather stats autotask being interrupted before maintenance window ends

Tags: oracle-12c, statistics, maintenance

a few months ago I managed to enlarge the maintenance windows for autotask on a pluggable database, this way:

```
BEGIN
  dbms_scheduler.disable(
    name  => 'WINDOW_NAME');
  dbms_scheduler.set_attribute(
    name      => 'WINDOW_NAME',
    attribute => 'DURATION',
    value     => numtodsinterval(6, 'hour'));
  dbms_scheduler.enable(
    name => 'WINDOW_NAME');
END;
/
```

This was what I got:

```
WINDOW_NAME      START_TIME                               DURATION
---------------- ---------------------------------------- ---------------
THURSDAY_WINDOW  08-JUL-21 10.00.00.241279 PM +02:00      +000 06:00:00
FRIDAY_WINDOW    09-JUL-21 10.00.00.241279 PM +02:00      +000 06:00:00
SATURDAY_WINDOW  10-JUL-21 10.00.00.241279 PM +02:00      +000 06:00:00
SUNDAY_WINDOW    11-JUL-21 10.00.00.241279 PM +02:00      +000 06:00:00
MONDAY_WINDOW    12-JUL-21 10.00.00.241279 PM +02:00      +000 06:00:00
TUESDAY_WINDOW   13-JUL-21 10.00.00.241279 PM +02:00      +000 06:00:00
WEDNESDAY_WINDOW 14-JUL-21 10.00.00.241279 PM +02:00      +000 06:00:00
```

But now, on that same pluggable db I'm noticing that since August 24th stats jobs are being stopped due to the end of the window:

```
TASK_NAME                 STATUS     CURRENT_JOB_NAME          LAST_TRY_DATE                       LAST_TRY_R
------------------------- ---------- ------------------------- ----------------------------------- ----------
gather_stats_prog         ENABLED                              12-SEP-21 03.00.09.858615 AM +02:00 STOPPED AT
                                                                                                    END OF MA
                                                                                                   INTENANCE
                                                                                                   WINDOW

auto_space_advisor_prog   ENABLED                              12-SEP-21 12.33.31.490404 AM +02:00 SUCCEEDED
AUTO_SQL_TUNING_PROG      ENABLED                              11-SEP-21 11.00.22.422336 PM +02:00 SUCCEEDED
```

At first I thought that it might be caused by some performance problem, but then I noticed that the jobs were still during 4 hours (default windows duration):

```
CLIENT_NAME                         JOB_NAME                  JOB_STATUS JOB_START_TIME                             JOB_DURATION
----------------------------------- ------------------------- ---------- ------------------------------------------ ---------------
auto optimizer stats collection     ORA$AT_OS_OPT_SY_9601     STOPPED    07-SEP-21 10.00.19.825083 PM EUROPE/VIENNA +000 03:59:44
auto optimizer stats collection     ORA$AT_OS_OPT_SY_9621     STOPPED    08-SEP-21 10.00.11.786102 PM EUROPE/VIENNA +000 03:59:53
```

I then noticed that the maintenance windows duration was still set to 4 hours on the container database:

```
WINDOW_NAME      START_TIME                               DURATION
---------------- ---------------------------------------- ---------------
SUNDAY_WINDOW    12-SEP-21 10.00.00.235575 PM +02:00      +000 04:00:00
MONDAY_WINDOW    13-SEP-21 10.00.00.235575 PM +02:00      +000 04:00:00
TUESDAY_WINDOW   14-SEP-21 10.00.00.235575 PM +02:00      +000 04:00:00
WEDNESDAY_WINDOW 15-SEP-21 10.00.00.235575 PM +02:00      +000 04:00:00
THURSDAY_WINDOW  16-SEP-21 10.00.00.235575 PM +02:00      +000 04:00:00
FRIDAY_WINDOW    17-SEP-21 10.00.00.235575 PM +02:00      +000 04:00:00
SATURDAY_WINDOW  18-SEP-21 10.00.00.235575 PM +02:00      +000 04:00:00
```

Should I modify the duration on the container too?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would certainly do that. Only oracle knows the internals and even there I have my doubts. But there is more to do. There are a lot of settings in gather statistics.

You seem to follow the brute force method. You might gain some benefits from studying the frequency of the tables, samplesizes and partitions. Involve a developer and use their knowledge about the table/application behavior. 4 hours is a long time to sample statistics in. When I am ready most of the times the sampling ends within an hour. Speaking about 10T databases with mixed workloads.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Do you know if there's any way to check on which objects the statistics took more time?

Comment: Not directly but check DBA tab stats history tables and the current statistics. See which tables/partitions are samples most. Are partitions in use?

Comment: Yes, some of the objects are partitioned. I'm sorry, what do you mean with "See which tables/partitions are samples most" ? Size sampling is not visible from that table

Comment: A table or partition that is sampled every day might be worth looking into. Also check the sample sizes. See https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/tgsql/options-for-optimizer-statistics-gathering.html#GUID-E798E1F6-FC85-456E-8F38-99534BE74492 in the stats hist tables you can also find the used sample sizes. For big tables set parallellism.  For partitioned tables set incremental statistics. Both can save lots of sampling time.